# how can we set google app account set with server

Tags: php, smtp

I'm trying to send mails from my server by google app.

I am using this php code :-

```
$to = "username@gmail.com";
$header = "From: username@netvigator.com";
$subject = "testing mail";
$message = "no reply pls";

ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("SMTP_PORT", 23);
ini_set("sendmail_from","username@fullpiracy.com");
ini_set("auth_username","username@fullpiracy.com");
ini_set("auth_password","password");

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was done with send mail open source library.

http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/

Answer (score 0):

I believe Gmail uses SSL (or TLS), so you should adjust your settings accordingly.

The port is usually **465** for ssl connection and **587** for TLS, and address are `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` and `tls://smtp.gmail.com` respectively.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page) is a link to a useful SO question that may be helpful.